# Do I have to go through security twice when transferring between Terminals 1 and 3 at Abu Dhabi airport?

Tags: airport-security, abu-dhabi

I am traveling from Beirut, Lebanon to Incheon, South Korea via Abu Dhabi. The itinerary says that I have to go from T1 to T3 for my transit. The maps I have downloaded say I have to go through security checks twice: once at T1 and another at T3. Is this true or will I be allowed to go without a second check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All international passengers arriving at Abu Dhabi airport have to go through security once. After that you can check your next airline on the screen or printed boarding pass which terminal to go.

There would be only 1 security when you will be entering and after passing there would be no additional security again

Answer (score 1):

I recently travelled Ahmedabad to Los Angeles. They did 3 security check ins on Abu Dhabi airport - don't know why. :)

I have to also clear CBP Customs for US also in the Abu Dhabi Airport. I wish this could be less time wasting but we don't want to negotiate with security too, as good cosmopolitan.

Comment: Where in the airport were the security checks? Terminal 1, 3?

Comment: Off course there is additional security if you are traveling to usa, In abu Dhabi the is already a us custom and immigration facility means you and your baggage would be scanned again. Once you clear us custom and immigration at abu Dhabi airport, there would be no additional custom and passport check in usa

Answer (score 0):

From the [official website of the airport](http://www.abudhabiairport.ae/english/airport-information/transit-information/international-connections.aspx):

> In order to ensure the highest levels of passenger security, each
>   terminal has a security check area at each point of entry, so you will
>   need to go through security again if you have moved between terminals.

Comment: wrong answer sir, i have been a frequent flyer of etihad airways and was using my flight from karachi to abu dhabi ey222 which lands at T1, and after that connecting flight ey19 to London which departs from T3, all the time going back and forth there is only 1 security check point after that both T1 and T3 are connected terminlas . it is just a matter of long walk

Comment: Interesting. I guess I'll just have to see which is correct. I'll mark the correct answer when I actually fly.

Comment: Also yubin i found this website which even shows a long walk pic from t1 to t3

Comment: Loungeindex.com  country UAE Abu Dhabi